# Form submission could not get full data when I use Angular to filling data before submission

Tags: angularjs

I want to submit a form data to an outside url, but I got problem when I used angular for filling data and submission.

Here is my form

```
<form name="frm" id="myForm" method="post" action="http://an-outside-url.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="NAME" ng-model="NAME">
        <input type="hidden" name="ADDRESS" ng-model="ADDRESS">
</form>
```

And here is my controller, after filling data to the form, I call to submit the form to specified url.

```
$rootScope.NAME = 'my name';
$rootScope.ADDRESS = 'my address';
$('#myForm').submit();
```

But I could not submit full of data as I expect. I think that calling `$('#myForm').submit();` causes a form submission before Angular complete it's digest cycle for binding data to form fields.

How I could solve this problem?

Comment: What is a trigger to submit? Do you want to submit in a initializing process of your controller?

Comment: Yes, in the initializing process.

Comment: But i see it's the same if i trigger event from elsewhere, maybe a button click for example

Comment: If you submit form on click event of a button, you could get what you want.

Comment: BTW I recommend you to use $http.post instead of `$('#myForm').submit()` as you do. If you insist to use it, you could try to wrap this line with $timeout service.

Comment: Ah, i understand, but i want to do filling data then submit in the same thread.

Comment: Would you like to explain the reason why you insist your way? I think the answer depends on  the reason.

Comment: Ah, i need to integrate with a payment gateway. The submission should be done automatically instead of triggered from an user action like button click for example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83934/discussion-between-yazaki-and-chin-nghe).